# Calling .trigger('create') causes JavaScript error

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this weird issue with jQuery Mobile that only occurs on page refresh (e.g. by pressing F5).

On the page in question, within the 'pageshow' event, the following is called:

```js
$('content').html(details.html).trigger('create');
```

This works perfectly fine when the page is navigated to, but once you stay on the page and refresh, the styles aren't applied and the following error appears in the JS console:

> TypeError: c[0] is undefined

However, if I push the `.trigger('create')` into a `setInterval` with a value of 1, it still throws the error but applies the styles correctly:

```js
$('content').html(details.html);
setInterval(function() {
   $('content').trigger('create');
}, 1);
```

Obviously this isn't ideal, so I was wondering if anyone has come across a similar problem, and if so what they did to fix it?